# Dynamically call javascript object function from html

Tags: javascript, html, function, object

I'm working on a kind of javascript text-based game engine. I have a javascript object with an 'onuse' method. This works fantastically when I use it like this:

```
var button = new CanvasObject();
button.text = "test" // Necessary for the next code sample
button.onuse = function(){ button.x += 1 }; // Some simple reaction;
```

I have code in a Canvas object that when drawing a CanvasObject will wrap it in a span tag like so:

```
<span onclick = "function{ button.x += 1 }">test</span>
// Or to make the HTML cleaner:
<span onclick = canvas.callFunction(5)>test</span>
// where canvas.callFunction will call the function needed.
// Canvas keeps an array of functions that can be called.
```

The Canvas will call the function, and since it uses 'absolute' terms, the line 'button.x += 1', will work fine. The problem is that I have another class that I extended from CanvasObject, for example, ButtonObject. I want the class definition to have an onuse function that is already defined. For example (using the inheritance technique lined out [here](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html))

```
ButtonObject.method('onuse', function(){
   this.x++; // Some function requiring 'this'.
});
```

When I called a function from the HTML using the first technique, my engine would just call it as an anonymous function. Then, 'this' then would be defined as the window. I want every instance of ButtonObject to have the same 'onuse' function, so defining it each time like I did with CanvasObject seems like a lot of extra code. One possible solution I thought of was to modify the way my engine works such that each object is given a 'name' property, that is equivalent to it's javascript name. This way the engine could simple write the string like this:

```
innerHTML += ( "<span onclick=' + buttonObjectInstance.name + ".onuse()'>" );
```

But this technique would require me to state the name of the object twice, every time I instantiate it, like this:

```
var startButton = ButtonObject('startButton');
```

Is this truly my only option? Or is there way to call a function in the context of the object without having the name of that object?

Comment: Maybe it is just the Fridays, but _say whaaaaaaaat?_ It sounds like you need to add that method to the object's `prototype`, but I honestly don't have any idea what you're doing.

Comment: @Mathletics - I was using that way earlier, but I changed it to Douglass Crockford's technique as linked in the question. This allows me to let ButtonObject inherit all functions from CanvasObject. As far as I know, this doesn't cause any problems in the code that relate to my question. Object functions are still called like 'button.doSomething()'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bind a function to this for later:

```
ButtonObject.method('onuse', function(){
   this.x++; // Some function requiring 'this'.
} .bind(ButtonObject)  );
```

of if not ButtonObject in the calling context, bind it to whatever holds your methods.

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction, so thanks for that. The problem now is that my function doesn't recognize functions that aren't defined in the constructor. For example, I have another `ButtonObject.method('render', function(){etc..})`. And when I try to call it in the bound 'onuse', it says that the method doesn't exist. I believe this is because it only binds the constructor.

Comment: from within a constructor, you'll probably want to bind to _this_ instead of ButtonObject; i wasn't sure how the rest of the code looked.

Comment: Ah thank you, this pretty much solved it. I put the method definition into the constructor, and bound it to 'this'. I was afraid that the 'inheriting' code would overwrite my function, but it worked out fine.